# Convolution limits of positive function

Tags: convolution

Why are the limits of the convolution of two positive functions $0$ and $t$?

$$(f \star g)(t) = \int_0^t f(x)g(t-x)\,dx \text{ for } f,g : [0,\infty) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$$

I understand the lower limit of 0 because both are non-negative functions, but why $t$?

Thank you!

Comment: You have your convolution slightly ajar. It should read $g(t-x)$, hopefully that answers your question.

Comment: See my edits for proper MathJax usage. In particular in expressions like $f\,dy\,dx$ the expressions like $dy$ and $dx$ are separated from their surroundings by a small space (likewise with $\Delta x$ in $f(x_i)\,\Delta x_i$ and in the denominator of the expression $\dfrac{\partial^2f}{\partial x\, \partial y},$ etc.) and \text{} is used with the word "for" between the integral and $f,g. \qquad$

Comment: @NinadMunshi: Yes, you are right. I copied the expression from Wikipedia, and it seems as I have made an error while switching tabs. No, the questions would be, then why not $\infty$ instead of $t$? I really can't wrap my head around convolution limits.

Comment: @MichaelHardy: Thank you for your corrections and especially for the comment. It really helps me to get better with my expressions! Until now I wasn't aware of \,

Comment: This isn't about _positive_ functions; it's about functions whose domain is the set of positive numbers. The values of the function don't have to be positive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the integrand term $f(x)g(t-x)$. If $x<0$, then $f(x)=0$. If $x>t$, $g(t-x)=0$. Thus for a fixed $t$, $f(x)g(t-x)$ is 0 outside the interval $x\in [0,t]$.

Comment: Oh, how could I not see this. It is so obvious now. Thanks a lot!